# Send SSH escape character programmatically

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

When I ssh (OpenSSH) to a server, I can type "~C" to enter ssh's command line and then open some tunnels. Is there a way to script this or write a C program to do it? I'd like to ssh to my server and then run a command to open the tunnels.

Comment: There are ways to do it. Are you asking us for code demonstrating how to do it? If so, you should show what you've tried, and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Tunnel from where to where? Generally, `ssh`'s `-L` and `-R` options are quite helpful (see `man ssh`).

Comment: Tin Man - If there is a way to do this please let me know how in general terms. In other words, after the client connects to the server, how can a program running on the server side open a tunnel on the client side?

Comment: -L and -R don't help as those are passed on the client side before the connection is established.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- inside a manually-established SSH session, no -- whatever a program outputs will go to its stdout
- otherwise you can write a program to drive a ssh session. Or you could use `expect` to drive one, as in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=220139 (or search expect + ssh for more examples)
- the program that drives the SSH client can use information printed by the server to open appropriate tunnels (by reading the server output, then simulating a ~C keypress when it has enough information)

Comment: Expect would work, but that would have to be run on the client side. I'm looking for a way to open the tunnel from the server side after the connection has already been made.

Comment: Whatever happens on the **server side will not open tunnels**. Think about what a security risk that would be. The tunnels are open by your ssh client in response to commands from your terminal (or whoever is driving ssh). Any tunnels you may desire can be described from the client side using -R or -L (if you disagree, provide a counterexample)

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the fact that your ssh client driver (e.g. expect) can read the server's output to figure out what tunnels to open. Perhaps that would help you?

Comment: The security risk is certainly true. The expect idea would work, but the goal is to make it easier for my end-users to open ports. It would be easier to teach them to use ~C than for them to run an expect script. But thanks for the idea. I didn't think it would be possible either, but I'm glad at least 1 person confirmed this.thanks.